# how to get customer cart_item list in webservice magento1.9.3?

Tags: magento-1.9

please check my code cart list not coming on "postman".

```
<?php
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 200);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 200);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if($_REQUEST['hashkey'] =='NXqXAgFZA0jiWp5t6+=lGpgWJXEkbo' AND $_REQUEST['custid'] != '' )
{

$customer = $_REQUEST['custid'];

require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

if($customer)
{
  $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $item)
{
   $id= $item->getId();
   $p_id = $item->getProductId();
   if (is_null($id)) {
     $ret[$id]['id'] = "";
   }else{
     $ret[$id]['id'] = $item->getProductId();
   }

   if (is_null($item->getName())) {
     $ret[$id]['name'] = "";
   }else{
     $ret[$id]['name'] = $item->getName();
   }

   if (is_null($item->getPrice())) {
     $ret[$id]['price'] = "";
   }else{
     $ret[$id]['price'] = round($item->getPrice(),4);
   }

    $ret[$id]['cart'] = "1";

   $ret[$id]['sku'] = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p_id)->getSku();;


if (is_null($item->getQty())) {
    $ret[$id]['qty'] = "";
}else{
    $ret[$id]['qty'] = $item->getQty();
}

  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($p_id);
  $productimage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail');
  $ret[$id] ['image'] = (string)$productimage;
}

}
    $ret = array_values($ret);
$retfinal=array("success"=>"1" ,"message"=>"cart Items List","addtocart"=>$ret );
$result=json_encode($retfinal);
echo $result;

} else{
   $ret['success'] = "0";
   $ret['message'] = "This is error message...";
   $result=json_encode($ret);
   echo $result;   
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Mage_Sales_Model_Quote class you can see the function to get customer quote by customer

/** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer **/

$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByCustomer($customer);

With customer quote you can get cart and cart items 
$cart->getAllVisibleItems()

Comment: Thanks its working